# NameError: name 'sizes' is not defined-PYTHON

Tags: python, error-handling, biopython

Could some one suggest me a way to resolve below error?

```
>>> from Bio import SeqIO
>>> sizes=[len(rec) for rec in SeqIO.parse("CE2Kb_2Kb_F01_2124_5.fasta", "fasta")
 len(seq), min(seq), max(seq)

>>> sizes

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    sizes
NameError: name 'sizes' is not defined**
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot to close your list comprehension.

Comment: Select code, and `Ctrl+K` to format it.

Comment: Thanks. Did ctrl+K thing. Still it keeps on coming.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you closed your list comprehension ...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Pfitz -- Why do you say this doesn't answer the question?  As posed, this question is un-answerable, but I saw one problem, and it's quite possible that fixing that could solve OP's problem.  Python could be applying line continuation within the brakets, so when you end up getting to `sizes` again, it hasn't been defined yet.  Of course, OP must have closed them at some point where it's not being shown (otherwise, nothing would have happened other than maybe a `SyntaxError`.)

Comment: To be honest this seems more like a comment than an answer to me. @mgilson